# Bootstrap HTML cant show after make button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have to make some buttons after minimize the page he can show the some buttons and show this but that can't show the menu why ?
Can I fix it ?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Full and Starving </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"> beranda </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> testing </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> coba </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Test </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included JQuery first as bootstrap needs JQuery. Working code :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/6ddhvbea/1/)

Code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container"> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Full and Starving </a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" > <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"> beranda </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> testing </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> coba </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Test </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```